# How to show more than one push in Android push section

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, phonegap-pushplugin

[SOLVED]

A stroke of brightness hit me while I was searching for the solution: by seeing that Cordova has been updated, the PushPlugin has been updated too.
In the version i was using, the snipped that I pasted in the question was not present.

I updated Cordova and the plugin... Now it works properly by using the 'notId' field from the backend! ;)

I leave the question below, for further readers!

Regards,

Rik

---

I'm developing a mobile application in Cordova/PhoneGap. I am using the PushPlugin (https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin) to implement the push notification mechanism.

When I send more than one push to my devices I can see only one of them on Android devices. iOS devices shows all the push notifications in the lock screen.

How can I show more than one notification in Android? I searched inside the documentation of the plugin and I found the following snippet inside the 'onMessage' method:

```
[...]
int notId = 0;

try {
    notId = Integer.parseInt(extras.getString("notId"));
}
catch(NumberFormatException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Number format exception - Error parsing Notification ID: " + e.getMessage());
}
catch(Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Number format exception - Error parsing Notification ID" + e.getMessage());
}

mNotificationManager.notify((String) appName, notId, mBuilder.build());
[...]
```

I have tried to set different 'notId' field in the back-end, but it does not seem to work...

Any other idea?

Thank you for your help,
    Rik.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this :
    notificationManager.notify((String)appName,(int) Calendar.getInstance()
                .getTimeInMillis(), mBuider.build()); //What you are doing wrong is setting each notification same id so they are replacing one another and this code create new id by time , so you can see multiple notification on the screen
```

Comment: I supposed that that was the problem. Being a plugin, I hope that there is a different way to solve the issue... If I do not find a different way to handle this, I will definitely adopt your solution.

Answer (score 0):

use a random number for notId and this will work such as:

```
   Random rnd = new Random();  
   int notId = rnd.nextInt(100);
```

instead of :

```
    int notId = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to chnage the notfication id because it's all time not the solution is that you have to use ramdom number concept

```
Random random = new Random();
int randomNumber = random.nextInt(9999 - 1000) + 1000;
notificationManager.notify(randomNumber, notification);
```